# Why are arrays of references illegal?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

The following code does not compile.

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int& arr[] = {a,b,c,8};
```

**What does the C++ standard say about this?**

I know I could declare a class that contains a reference, then create an array of that class, as shown below.  But I really want to know why the code above doesn't compile.

```
struct cintref
{
    cintref(const int & ref) : ref(ref) {}
    operator const int &() { return ref; }
private:
    const int & ref;
    void operator=(const cintref &);
};

int main() 
{
  int a=1,b=2,c=3;
  //typedef const int &  cintref;
  cintref arr[] = {a,b,c,8};
}
```

It is possible to use `struct cintref` instead of `const int &` to simulate an array of references.

Comment: Even if the array was valid, storing a raw '8' value in it wouldn't work. If you did "intlink value = 8;", it would die horribly, because it's pretty much just translated into "const int & value = 8;". A reference must reference a variable.

Comment: `intlink value = 8;` does work. check if you does not believe.

Comment: As Alexey points out, it is perfectly valid to bind an rvalue to a const reference.

Comment: What _doesn't_ work is that `operator=`. References cannot be reseated. If you really want such semantics - though I've not personally found a situation in which they're practically useful - then `std::reference_wrapper` would be the way to do it, as it actually stores a pointer but provides reference-like `operator`s and _does_ allow reseating. But then I'd just use a pointer!

Comment: The operator= is private and not implemented, aka what in C++11 is =delete.

Comment: @underscore_d - In this context, the "=" is performing initialization, not assignment. So that is not the problem. Not sure I have seen a good rationale yet, actually

Comment: @JimmyHartzell Good point, thanks. I'm so used to C++11 now that I often don't recognise the old tricks!

Answer (score 214, accepted):

Answering to your question about standard I can cite the **C++ Standard §8.3.2/4**:

> There shall be no references to references, **no arrays of references**, and no pointers to references.

That's because references are not objects and doesn't occupy the memory so doesn't have the address. You can think of them as the aliases to the objects. Declaring an array of nothing has not much sense.

Comment: What more is there to say?

Comment: there should be arrays of references for the same reason we have arrays of pointers, same information but different handling, no?

Comment: C++ standard says - ** your logic, let ours be!

Comment: I fell in love with C and right now, I am learning C++ (just to pass the class, I have to admit). Dealing with a home assignment, I was happy that finaly I found references useful - *oh wait*, no arrays of references! Too bad. Thanks for short answer.

Comment: If compiler developers did decide, as an extension, to allow arrays of references, then would it be a success? Or are there some real problems - perhaps ambiguous code - that would just make it too darn confusing to define this extension?

Comment: @David For what purpose would you want an array of references though?... In C++?

Comment: @SuperCat The obvious use case is to pass a collection of objects into a function by reference, without needing a separate parameter for each one.  Sure, I can do that with an array of pointers, but that mandates all the NULL pointer checking ugliness that references were created to get rid of in the first place.

Comment: @dgnuff if the references really belong together, why not have the objects themselves within a collection, and pass a reference to the collection itself? this seems better than either an array of pointers or an array of references (which is not possible)

Comment: @tstittleburg that is certainly a solution, but has one huge shortcoming.  I can't iterate over the members of a collection, either a `struct` or a  `class`, using a `for` loop.  If the collection has a couple of hundred members, that's going to make processing them all extremely painful, while an array and a `for` loop could do the job in 20 lines or less.

Comment: @dgnuff sorry I wasn't clear. what I meant by collection was an iterable collection like a vector or a list. passing a reference to such a collection would let you do this.

Comment: @tstittleburg OK, but now we're right back to where we started, because your iterable container can't currently contain references -- edit -- std::reference_wrapper<> notwithstanding, but then that solves the original problem, does it not?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I _think_ the real reason - which is so conspicuously absent from this & similar discussions - is that if one had an array of references, how would one possibly disambiguate between the address of an element & the address of its referent? The immediate objection to 'You can't put a reference in an array/container/whatever' is that you _can_ put a `struct` whose sole member is a reference. But then, by doing so, you've now got both a reference & a parent object to name... which now means you can unambiguously state which address you want. Seems obvious... so why has no one said it?

Comment: @AaronMcDaid ...& by not having a clear way to take the address of an _element_, rather than the referred object, you lose the ability to perform (consistent) address arithmetic between elements. So now, you don't actually have an array. You'd have something that initially looked like an array but that would be unable to do many of the things that people expect from arrays. So to me, even if we limited it by specifying 'X address always wins' or providing disambiguating syntax... it would be unacceptably ambiguous (more so than the rest of C++!) wrt 'real' arrays from a syntactic point of view

Comment: @polyglot `What more is there to say?` A rationale for _why_? I'm all about the Standard, but just citing it and assuming that's the end of the discussion seems like a sure-fire way to destroy users' critical thought - along with any potential for the language to evolve, e.g. beyond limitations of omission or artificial restriction. There's too much 'because the Standard says' here - and not enough 'and it is very sensible to say that, due to the following practical reasons'. I don't know why upvotes flow so eagerly to answers that only say the former without even trying to explore the latter.

Comment: It's defined in the language to be outside the syntax.  Furthermore, a reference is in essence a immutable address/label to a primary value.  Take the example `int &i = 1;`  Where is the int created?  It's not on the stack frame because by declaring i as a reference, `i` itself is allocated no space on the stack.  How would it make sense to create a reference to something which has no allocation semantics?

Comment: What I'm not clear on, is if I can do const std::string& foo = "some text"; why SHOULDN'T I be ABLE to do const std::string& fooArray[]= {"one", "two", "three"};

Comment: @polyglot, I logged in just to upvote your comment.  I paid for college classes as a young man where the instructor simply said, "because that's the standard," or some such wasteful thing!

Comment: Max: you should check his first comment. And then, check @underscore_d 's comment.

Comment: What do you mean references don't occupy memory? If you put a reference as a member inside a class it takes up space.

Comment: References seem like a great idea, but when all is said and done they are nothing else than poor man's pointers which can be used with `.` instead of `->`.

Comment: The "why" comes down primarily down to how the two are handled internally. Pointer is an actual thing, a variable created in memory, that contains a memory address of something. You can copy, duplicate, arrange, change them like every variable. Reference is just an abstraction that exists in the compiler's "mind". There's no address, no value stored, it's just a nickname for something else. In Java references are more substantial - essentially pointers sugar-coated with an automatic dereferencing interface on top. In C++, they have no such substance. They don't exist in the compiled code.

Answer (score 73):

References are not objects. They don't have storage of their own, they just reference existing objects. For this reason it doesn't make sense to have arrays of references.

If you want a light-weight *object* that references another object then you can use a pointer. You will only be able to use a `struct` with a reference member as objects in arrays if you provide explicit initialization for all the reference members for all `struct` instances. References cannot be default initalized.

**Edit:** As jia3ep notes, in the standard section on declarations there is an explicit prohibition on arrays of references.

Comment: References are same in their nature as constant pointers, and therefore they take up some memory (storage) to point to something.

Comment: Not necesserily. The compiler might be able to avoid storing the address, if it's a reference to local object for instance.

Comment: Not necessarily. References in structures usually take up some storage. Local references often don't. Either way, in the strict standard sense, references are not objects and (this was new to me) named references aren't actually _variables_.

Comment: Well, those are compiler-dependent optimizations. In general case references do take some memory.

Comment: Yes, but this is an implementation detail. An _object_ in the C++ model is a typed region of storage. A reference is explicitly not an object and there is no guarantee that it takes up storage in any particular context.

Comment: I don't agree that it doesn't 'make sense' to have arrays of refs.  It may be that it would tend to complicate the general semantics of the language beyond repair.  I've often written things like   thing_t const &which = i? thing2 : thing1;  inside a loop where i is 0,1, in order to treat thing1 & thing2 across the loops. Declaring a local array of refs would extend this cleanly to reference many things. If references are 'abstract entities with no storage', then you could have an abstract array of them which can only be used with []. That's the rub, you could not get general array semantics.

Comment: Put it this way: you *can* have a struct of nothing but 16 refs to foo's, and use it in exactly the same way as I'd want to use my array of refs - except that you can't index into the 16 foo references. This is a language wart IMHO.

Comment: As an aside, the STL (say mostly value semantics oriented) - does provide `std::reference_wrapper<>` as one method specifically for reference semantics (say as an alternative to using [smart] pointers).

Answer (score 40):

This is an interesting discussion. Clearly arrays of refs are outright illegal, but IMHO the reason why is not so simple as saying 'they are not objects' or 'they have no size'. I'd point out that arrays themselves are not full-fledged objects in C/C++ - if you object to that, try instantiating some stl template classes using an array as a 'class' template parameter, and see what happens. You can't return them, assign them, pass them as parameters. ( an array param is treated as a pointer). But it is legal to make arrays of arrays.
References do have a size that the compiler can and must calculate - you can't sizeof() a reference, but you can make a struct containing nothing but references. It will have a size sufficient to contain all the pointers which implement the references. You can't instantiate such a struct without initializing all the members:

```
struct mys {
 int & a;
 int & b;
 int & c;
};
...
int ivar1, ivar2, arr[200];
mys my_refs = { ivar1, ivar2, arr[12] };

my_refs.a += 3  ;  // add 3 to ivar1
```

In fact you can add this line to the struct definition

```
struct mys {
 ...
 int & operator[]( int i ) { return i==0?a : i==1? b : c; }
};
```

...and now I have something which looks a LOT like an array of refs:

```
int ivar1, ivar2, arr[200];
mys my_refs = { ivar1, ivar2, arr[12] };

my_refs[1] = my_refs[2]  ;  // copy arr[12] to ivar2
&my_refs[0];               // gives &my_refs.a == &ivar1
```

Now, this is not a real array, it's an operator overload; it won't do things that arrays normally do like sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]), for instance. But it does exactly what I want an array of references to do, with perfectly legal C++.
Except (a) it's a pain to set up for more than 3 or 4 elements, and (b) it's doing a calculation using a bunch of ?: which could be done using indexing (not with normal C-pointer-calculation-semantics indexing, but indexing nonetheless). I'd like to see a very limited 'array of reference' type which can actually do this. I.e. an array of references would not be treated as a general array of things which are references, but rather it would be a new 'array-of-reference' thing which effectively maps to an internally generated class similar to the one above (but which you unfortunately *can't* make with templates).

this would probably work, if you don't mind this kind of nasty: recast '*this' as an array of int *'s and return a reference made from one: (not recommended, but it shows how the proper 'array' would work):

```
 int & operator[]( int i ) { return *(reinterpret_cast<int**>(this)[i]); }
```

Comment: You *can* do this in C++11 `std::tuple<int&,int&,int&> abcref = std::tie( a,b,c)` - which creates an "array" of references that can only be indexed by compile-time constants using std::get.  But you can't do `std::array<int&,3> abcrefarr = std::tie( a,b,c)`. Maybe there's a way to do it that I don't know of. It seems to me that there should be a way to write a specialization of `std::array<T&,N>` which *can* do this - and thus a function `std::tiearray(...)` which returns one such (or allow `std::array<T&,N>` to accept initializer containing addresses = {&v1, &v2 etc})

Comment: Your proposal is silly (IMO), and your last line assumes an int can hold a pointer (usually false, at least where I work). But this is the only answer here with a legitimate rationale for why arrays of references are forbidden, so +1

Comment: @Nemo it wasn't really intended as a proposal, but just to illustrate that the functionality of such a thing is not absurd on its face. I note in my last comment that c++ has things which come close. Also, the last line you refer to assumes that memory implementing a _reference_ to an int can be usefully aliased as a pointer-to-int -- the struct contains references, not ints -- and that tends to be true. I'm not claiming it's portable (or even safe from 'undefined behaviour' rules). it was meant to illustrate how indexing could be used under-the-hood to avoid all the `?:`

Comment: Fair enough. But I do think this idea is "absurd on its face", and this is precisely why arrays of references are disallowed. An array is, first and foremost, a container. All containers need an iterator type for standard algorithms to apply. The iterator type for "array of T" is normally "T *". What would be the iterator type for an array of references? The amount of language hacking it would take to deal with all of these issues is ridiculous for an essentially useless feature. Actually maybe I will make this an answer of my own :-)

Comment: @Nemo It doesn't need to be part of the core language, so the iterator type being 'custom' is no big deal. All the various container types have their iterator types. In this case the iterator, dereferenced, would reference the target objs, not the refs in the array, which is fully consistent with the array's behaviour.  It may still require a bit of new C++ behaviour to support as a template The very simple `std::array<T,N>`, easily defined in app code, wasn't added to std:: until c++11, presumably because it's warty to have this with no way to do `= {1,2,3};` Was that 'language hacking'?

Comment: .. and at that point there's no reason the implementation needs to contain references. It can contain an array of pointers, but the `operator []` and iterator would act as if it contained reference (you couldn't change the pointers). The only part missing  is the initialization, as far as I can see. Including extending lifetime of any temps.

Answer (score 37):

Comment to your edit:

Better solution is `std::reference_wrapper`.

Details:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/reference_wrapper/

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4;
    using intlink = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
    intlink arr[] = {a,b,c,d};
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Given `int& arr[] = {a,b,c,8};`, what is `sizeof(*arr)` ?

Everywhere else, a reference is treated as being simply the thing itself, so `sizeof(*arr)` should simply be `sizeof(int)`. But this would make array pointer arithmetic on this array wrong (assuming that references are not the same widths as ints). To eliminate the ambiguity, it's forbidden.

Comment: Yep. You can't have an array of something unless it has a size. What is the size of a reference?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Make a `struct` whose only member is that reference and find out..?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, not the stupid pedantic one that simply throws the standard at the OP.

Comment: Maybe there is a typo. "assuming that references are not the same widths is ints" should be "assuming that references are not the same widths as ints". Change *is* to *as*.

Comment: But wait, by this logic you couldn't have reference member variables.

Answer (score 13):

An array is implicitly convertable to a pointer, and [pointer-to-reference is illegal in C++](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-417237.html)

Comment: It is true you cannot have a pointer to a reference, but this is not the reason that you cannot have an array of references.  Rather they are both symptoms of the fact that references are not objects.

Comment: A struct can contain nothing but references, and it will have a size proportional to the number of them. If you did have an array of refs 'arr', the normal array-to-pointer conversion would not make sense, since 'pointer-to-reference' doesn't make sense. *but* it would make sense to just use arr[i] , in the same way as st.ref when 'st' is a struct containing a ref.  Hmm. But &arr[0] would give the address of the first referenced object, and &arr[1]- &arr[0] would not be the same as &arr[2]-&arr[1] - it would create a lot of strangeness.

Answer (score 10):

Because like many have said here, references are not objects. they are simply aliases. True some compilers might implement them as pointers, but the standard does not force/specify that. And because references are not objects, you cannot point to them. Storing elements in an array means there is some kind of index address (i.e., pointing to elements at a certain index); and that is why you cannot have arrays of references, because you cannot point to them.

Use boost::reference_wrapper, or boost::tuple instead; or just pointers.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the answer is very simple and it has to do with semantic rules of references and how arrays are handled in C++.

**In short:
References can be thought of as structs which don't have a default constructor, so all the same rules apply.**

1) Semantically, references don't have a default value. References can only be created by referencing something. References don't have a value to represent the absence of a reference.

2) When allocating an array of size X, program creates a collection of default-initialized objects. Since reference doesn't have a default value, creating such an array is semantically illegal.

This rule also applies to structs/classes which don't have a default constructor. The following code sample doesn't compile:

```
struct Object
{
    Object(int value) { }
};

Object objects[1]; // Error: no appropriate default constructor available
```

Comment: You can create an array of `Object`, you just have to make sure to initialize them all: `Object objects[1] = {Object(42)};`. Meanwhile, you can't create an array of references, even if you initialize all of them.

Answer (score 4):

You can get fairly close with this template struct.
However, you need to initialize with expressions that are pointers to T, rather than T; and so, though you can easily make a 'fake_constref_array' similarly, you won't be able to bind that to rvalues as done in the OP's example ('8');

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<class T, int N> 
struct fake_ref_array {
   T * ptrs[N];
  T & operator [] ( int i ){ return *ptrs[i]; }
};

int A,B,X[3];

void func( int j, int k)
{
  fake_ref_array<int,3> refarr = { &A, &B, &X[1] };
  refarr[j] = k;  // :-) 
   // You could probably make the following work using an overload of + that returns
   // a proxy that overloads *. Still not a real array though, so it would just be
   // stunt programming at that point.
   // *(refarr + j) = k  
}

int
main()
{
    func(1,7);  //B = 7
    func(2,8);     // X[1] = 8
    printf("A=%d B=%d X = {%d,%d,%d}\n", A,B,X[0],X[1],X[2]);
        return 0;
}
```

--> A=0 B=7 X = {0,8,0}

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to all the conversation.
Since arrays requires consecutive memory locations to store the item, so if we create an array of references then it's not guaranteed that they will be at consecutive memory location so accessing will be a problem and hence we can't even apply all the mathematical operations on array.

Comment: Consider the below code from the original question:             int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
int& arr[] = {a,b,c,8};         There's very less possibility that a,b,c will reside at consecutive memory location.

Comment: That is far from the main problem with the concept of holding references in a container.

Answer (score 2):

A reference object has no size. If you write `sizeof(referenceVariable)`, it will give you the size of the object referenced by `referenceVariable`, not that of the reference itself. It has no size of its own, which is why the compiler can't calculate how much size the array would require.

Comment: if so how then a compiler can calculate size of a struct containing only a ref?

Comment: Compiler does know the physical size of a reference - its the same as a pointer. References are, in fact, semantically glorified pointers. The difference between pointers and references is that references have quite a few semantic rules placed on them in order to reduce the number of bugs you might create as compared with pointers.

Answer (score 2):

When you store something in an array , its size needs to be known (since array indexing relies on the size). Per the C++ standard It is unspecified whether or not a reference requires storage, as a result indexing an array of references would not be possible.

Comment: But by putting said reference in a `struct`, magically everything becomes specified, well-defined, guaranteed, and of deterministic size. Why, therefore, does this seemingly totally artificial difference exist?

Comment: ...of course, if one actually starts to think about what the wrapping `struct` confers, some good possible answers begin to suggest themselves - but to me, no one has done so yet, despite this being one of the immediate challenges to all the common rationales for why you can't use unwrapped refs.

Answer (score 0):

Consider an array of pointers. A pointer is really an address; so when you initialize the array, you are analogously telling the computer, "allocate this block of memory to hold these X numbers (which are addresses of other items)." Then if you change one of the pointers, you are just changing what it points to; it is still a numerical address which is itself sitting in the same spot.

A reference is analogous to an alias. If you were to declare an array of references, you would basically be telling the computer, "allocate this amorphous blob of memory consisting of all these different items scattered around."

Comment: Why, then, does making a `struct` whose only member is a reference result in something completely legal, predictable, and non-amorphous? Why must a user wrap a reference for it to magically gain array-capable powers, or is it just an artificial restriction? IMO no answer has directly addressed this. I assume the rebuttal is 'The wrapping object ensures you _can_ use value semantics, in the form of the wrapping object, so it ensures you can have the guarantees of values, which are needed because e.g. how would one disambiguate between element and referee address'... Is that what you meant?

Answer (score -2):

Actually, this is a mixture of C and C++ syntax.

You should **either** use pure C arrays, which cannot be of references, since reference are part of C++ only. **Or** you go the C++ way and use the `std::vector` or `std::array` class for your purpose.

As for the edited part: Even though the `struct` is an element from C, you define a constructor and operator functions, which make it a C++ `class`. Consequently, your `struct` would not compile in pure C!

Comment: What's your point? `std::vector` or `std::array` cannot contain references either. The C++ Standard is quite explicit that no container can.