# Change read-only variables as a target in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following structure of a class for read-only variables (principle taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424042/class-variables-public-access-read-only-but-private-access-read-write))

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    Test test;

    cout << test.x << endl; // Should be 0.
    test.f(test.x);
    cout << test.x << endl; // Should be 10.

return 0;
}
```

with the class Test

```
#ifndef __CPP_Playground__test__
#define __CPP_Playground__test__

#include <iostream>

class Test {
private:
    int x_;

public:
    const int &x;
    void f(int target);
    Test() : x(x_) {}
};

#endif /* defined(__CPP_Playground__test__) */
```

and the appropriate cpp file

```
#include "test.h"

void Test::f(int target){
    target = 10;
};
```

But it does not work. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to initialize `x_` in the constructor. And do something that actually has an effect in `Test::f()`.

Comment: But that is my question: How can I change it so that it does have an effect?

Comment: Change the value of something that is not a local variable? Look at `Test::f()`. What is it doing? Nothing.

Comment: And HOW can I change the value of x_ instead of the local variable but having the target variable? So that I could add an additional read-only variable int y_ with const int &y and also use function f to set it's value to 10?

Comment: `x_ = 10` would be one way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to subvert const-correctness like this, then you'll have to pass by reference (so that you can modify the variable, not a local copy), and use an evil cast to get around the type system's protection against such craziness.

```
void Test::f(int const &target){
    const_cast<int&>(target) = 10;
};
```

This will have undefined behaviour if the reference is bound to a `const` object.

Usually, it would make more sense for member functions to access the private variables themselves; and it would be better to provide read-only access via a "getter" function rather than a reference, since that would take up no extra storage in the object.

(Also, you shouldn't use [reserved names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783) like `__CPP_Playground__test__`)

Answer (score 0):

```
void f(int target);
```

You're defining the parameter `target` to be passed by value, i.e. as a copy. Thus changing `target` inside `f()` will have no effect on the variable you passed to `f()`.

To be able to modify an object passed to a function, the function needs to take that object as a reference. To declare `f()` to take a reference parameter:

```
void f(int& target);
```

Now you can modify the variable passed to `f()` inside the function and it will change also outside the function.

---

```
cout << test.x << endl; // Should be 0.
```

False. You haven't initialized `x_` so the value of `test.x` can be anything. It is undefined.

---

```
test.f(test.x);
```

This will result in an error after defining `f()` to accept a reference variable, because `test.x` is `const` (i.e. it can't be modified) and `f()` needs a non-`const` reference.