# Vector elements in c++ always set to last element

Tags: c++, vector

I want to store members of a class into a vector. In my class, I have some private variables that I access via constant pointers so that they are protected from being changed ([see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424042/class-variables-public-access-read-only-but-private-access-read-write)). Problem: When I add instances of the class into a vector during a loop and access them afterwards, all elements seem to be the last one added. Here's a MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class myClass {
private:
    int x_;

    void init(int x) {
        x_ = x;
    }

public:
    const int &x;

    myClass(int x) : x(x_) {
        init(x);
    };
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    vector<myClass> myVector;

    // Does not work
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        myVector.push_back(myClass(j));
    }
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        cout << "1st attempt: " << myVector.at(j).x << endl;
    }
    myVector.clear();

    // Works
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        myVector.push_back(myClass(j));
        cout << "2nd attempt: " << myVector.at(j).x << endl;
    }
    myVector.clear();

    // Works also
    myVector.push_back(myClass(0));
    myVector.push_back(myClass(1));
    myVector.push_back(myClass(2));
    for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
        cout << "3rd attempt: " << myVector.at(j).x << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ovious question: What am I doing wrong and can I fix it?

Comment: My gut feeling is that it has something to do with the object you create is being copied, and the member variable `x` will reference the `x_` member variable of the temporary object created by e.g. `myClass(j)`. In other words, try to create a copy-constructor which makes sure the `x` variable references the own `x_` variable.

Comment: can u post the output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong and can I fix it?

Well this idea looks misguided in general.  Putting that aside: if you want to "fix it" you need to think about what is happening when you `push_back`:

```
for (int j=0; j<3; j++) {
    myVector.push_back(myClass(j));
}
```

You are passing the class by value, so the copy constructor is invoked.  Hence push_back isn't getting `myClass(j)`, it's getting a copy.  Yet you didn't write a copy constructor...so where is your copy constructor coming from?  You're getting the compiler default, and it's just going to say the copy's `int &x` gets the same value as the original *(as opposed to the new object's x_.)*

This means that the reference inside of the copy in the vector is to the original object you passed in as `myClass(j)`.  Yet that original parameter is disposed after the `push_back` call is finished.  The memory space is probably reused each time through the loop which is why you see the last stale value.  Try running this through [Valgrind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind) or similar, it will probably pick up a problem.

You can get around this by writing your own copy constructor that does what you actually meant:

```
class myClass {
private:
    int x_;

    void init(int x) {
        x_ = x;
    }

public:
    const int &x;

    myClass(int x) : x(x_) {
        init(x);
    };

    myClass(myClass const & other) : x_ (other.x_), x(x_) {
    }
};
```

This way you are explicitly telling the compiler about your implicit desire to link the `int const &` to the `int`.  If you don't tell it, it has no way of knowing they are related at all.

But there are probably more than a few reasons not to do this kind of interface in the first place.  Just use a normal accessor method unless you've thought of a really good reason to do otherwise.

*(Take note also of @JoachimPileborg's suggestion of emplace_back, which is good to know about.)*

Comment: I guess there is no way to somehow reduce this to a single constructor method? With this I would have to do x(x_) twice for each variable I have in my class.

Comment: @DaPhil There is a sort of "Modern C++" idealization that *most of the time* you don't write copy constructors, move constructors, or even destructors...you let the compiler do it all for you.  *(smart pointers and such help to reach this goal)*.  But on your method here, if you find that you have more than one of these variables then you could make a sort of wrapper struct that holds them, template against it, and then do one reference initialization for it.  See for instance [QSharedDataPointer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on my comment...

When you do

```
myVector.push_back(myClass(0));
```

you create a *temporary* object with `myClass(0)`, an object which is destructed once the `push_back` function have returned. This temporary object is *copied* into the vector, and I think that the the member variable `x` in the copy will reference the member variable `x_` of the temporary object. That will of course lead to *undefined behavior* when you later use `x` which now references data in a destructed object.

There are two ways of solving this:

1. Use [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of `push_back`.
2. Add a copy-constructor which makes `x` reference the objects own `x_` variable.

Comment: I tried emplace_back since this seems to be the easier attempt. But it gives me the same output as push_back. Thanks anyway for your help.

Answer (score 1):

When you add an object to a `vector` it is copied across, invoking the class' copy constructor. Because `myClass` has a reference member, the default copy constructor won't work for the semantics you want, so you need to define your own:

```
myClass (const myClass& rhs) : x(x_) {
    init(rhs.x);
}
```

While you're at it, you might want to define an assignment operator as well:

```
myClass& operator= (const myClass& rhs) {
    x_ = rhs.x;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's easily fixed by repairing the definition of myClass, thus:

```
class myClass {
private:

public:
    const int x;

    myClass(int x_) : x(x_) {
    };
};
```

rational:

myClass implements the data-is-interface idiom which is fine, but if you're going to expose data do so by exposing the actual data - not a reference to it.

Remember that a reference is really a pointer underneath so it contains a memory address, and also that its presence in your class prevents the automatic generation of a move constructor.