# References in C++ and its memory requirement

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management

Suppose if I write the following code

```
int i=10;
int &j=i; //a reference in C++,don't confuse it with pointers & address
```

Does `j` takes any space in the memory as its simply a reference?

Comment: `int &j=i;` is invalid conversion.

Comment: @AmoghDikshit THen explain why, the OP clearly doesn't understand his mistake.

Comment: The `j` is a reference ,if you are confusing it with pointers.

Comment: Don't you feel this is wrong from your output 10 20 that its not possible. if j is reference which points to i so when you change j's value to 20 which is actually points to i then both's value should have to be 20 according to concept but that's not happening. Read about reference in detail.

Comment: int &j=i; conversion not possible

Comment: First you are using reference to a `CONST` For the answer of your question in the first place,  You should take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179937/how-does-a-c-reference-look-memory-wise

Comment: OK Thanks for making me correct,actually the book correct.That was the mistake of author.Please see the edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you are doing invalid initialization of `&j` as said by Luchian.

A reference is just a name given to the variable's memory location.You can access the contents of the variable through either the original variable name or the reference. You can read the following declaration :

```
int &j=i;
```

as:

`j` is an integer reference initialized to `i`.

Well, their occupying space is implementation dependent,Its not that they are stored somewhere,  you can think of them just as a label.

> **From C++ Standard (§ 8.3.2 #4)**
>
> It is **unspecified** whether or not a reference requires storage

The emphasis is mine.

**NOTE--**References are usually used for function argument lists and function return values.

Comment: Compilers implement references as pointers and thus they do consume space.

Comment: @NikosC. Sometimes.  As a local variable, I'd be surprised if any compiler allocated memory for the reference.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind a non-`const` reference to a `const` value. The compiler should give you an error:

> invalid initialization of reference of type ‘int&’ from expression of type ‘const int’

Even if you do get around this (with, for example, a `const_cast`), the code will have undefined behavior because you're modifying an originally `const` value.

> Does i takes any space in the memory as its simply a reference?

That's an implementation detail - it could be optimized out completely. What you need to know is that `j` is just a nickname for `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Error when you try to assign the reference to a constant value
"error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'int &'"