# If C++ reference doesn't occupy additional memory, why the assembly code looks like this?

Tags: c++

Based on what i know, C++ reference doesn't take a memory.
Because it is just an alias of a variable that reference is pointing to.

But When I compile the simple code and see the assembly by using lldb, I saw the result like below.

```
int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int &refToInt = a;
}

0x100003f90 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
0x100003f91 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x100003f94 <+4>: xorl   %eax, %eax
0x100003f96 <+6>:  movl   $0xa, -0x4(%rbp)
0x100003f9d <+13>: leaq   -0x4(%rbp), %rcx
0x100003fa1 <+17>: movq   %rcx, -0x10(%rbp)
```

I think the reference is using memory -0x10 isn't it??

I want to know what is happening

Thank you

Comment: Who told you references are free of cost? In fact a reference can be implemented using a pointer and that means it'll occupy the same space as the pointer. With that said, compilers are intelligent and they try to avoid that cost by optimizing it away whenever they can.

Comment: A reference is a pointer in disguise, it does occupy memory in general, unless optimized away. Though in this case any sane compiler would optimize it away, if you enable optimizations. Though it would also optimize away the entire program.

Comment: And no it isn't "just an alias", you can even use them as member variables. For now just think of them as pointers that MUST point to a valid object (cannot be `nullptr`). And you don't even have compiler optimizations enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [References in C++ and its memory requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853767/references-in-c-and-its-memory-requirement). TLDR: It is **unspecified** whether or not a reference requires storage.