# pointers and reference tricky code

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I have this simple piece of code :

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
int* c[] = {&a,&b};
int& d[] = {a,b};
int x = *c[0]+d[1];
```

If the following works

```
int &d = a;
```

I can't understand why the line 3 and 4 generates an error. :-s

It really makes no sense to me :(

Comment: If you want to ask 2 questions, then feel free two spawn 2 different threads. It's free in SO. Just cross check whether it's asked before or not.

Comment: @iammilind: I went ahead and remove the second question and references to "inheritance". I am pretty it is a duplicate anyway, as this shows up from time to time.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: And now second part of my answer has no meaning. :(

Comment: @Als: There was not second part when I did it !

Comment: And mine, and the new one. I think the edit should be reverted.

Comment: @DavidHammen: I think the question should be split, and the answers (and bits of) accompany the relevant part. Or we could just close it, I'm just looking for duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++: why can't we have references to references or array of references?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321578/c-why-cant-we-have-references-to-references-or-array-of-references)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int& d[] = {a,b};
```

You cannot create an array of references. It is not allowed by the C++ Standard.For it to be allowed the entire type mechanism would have to be re-written.

```
int x = *c[0]+d[1];
```

Gives you an error because the compiler cannot make out the type of `d`, since there is a compilation error on the previous line where you declare `d`.

---

```
B b[2];
```

Creates two objects of type `B` hence calls `B()` twice.

```
b[1]=D();
```

Creates an object of type `D`. For which it calls constructor of the class itself and its Base class, resulting in calls `B()` and `D()`. The created object is stored at array index `1`. However since the array is of type `B` ***[Object Slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c)*** takes place and all the derived members of the object are sliced off. Essentially, the object at `b[1]` is now of the type `B`

```
b[1].print();
```

Calls `print()` method on object type `B`(*See explanation above why it is type `B`*)

Answer (score 2):

for the first part see Als's response. The second part:

- first two constructors come in for the 2 elements of the array.
- third B constructor is the base of D
- then a D constructor
- then D is being destroyed, together with B since it was a temporary object
- then the B's print method is called since it is not virtual
- and then the two B elements from the array are destroyed

Answer (score 1):

Question #1

```
int& d[] = {a,b};
```

You can't make an array of references. Arrays contain objects. Instances, primitives, and pointers are objects. References aren't.

Question #2, answer elided due to the change in the question.