# Technicalities involved with array of references

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I wrote this code for the [following problem](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/REPFREE). My compiler is givin me the following error-     [Error] declaration of 'a' as array of references. What is the problem?

```
void repfunc(int& a[],int size){

    for(int i=size-1;i>=0;--i){

            if(a[i]==0){
                a[i]=1;
                return;
            }

        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;--ji){

            if(a[i]==a[j]&&a[i]!=9){
                ++a[i];
                a[i]%=10;
                return;
            }
            else if(a[i]==a[j]&&a[i]==9){
                a[j-1]++;
                a[j-1]%=10;

                    FOR(k, 1,size-j){
                        a[k]=k;
                    }

                return;
            }
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: You can't have an array of references, that's the problem (references are not objects).

Comment: [Why arrays of references are illegal?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1164266/96780)

Comment: why not? and what do i do?

Comment: To find out why, Please follow the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1164266/96780) in my comment above. Scroll down to the answers. About "what do I do", well, you still have two arrays to choose - array of objects and array of pointers.

Comment: then how do i pass an array to a function which can edit the array, without declaring the array global?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error says, you can't have an array of references. It looks like you're actually trying to pass an array by reference. You can (sort of) do that by changing it to take a pointer to the start of the array:

```
void repfunc(int a[], int size)  // equivalent to "int * a"
```

Since arrays are convertible to pointers, this will do the right thing if the argument is an array

```
int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
repfunc(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
```

Alternatively, you could accept a reference to an array of the correct size:

```
template <size_t size>
repfunc(int (&a)[size])
```

allowing the size to be deduced automatically

```
int a[4] = {1,2,3,4};
repfunc(a);
```

but note that this will only work if `a` is actually an array; not, for example an pointer to a dynamically allocated array.

Comment: @Paranaix: Indeed, I've added a note about that.

Comment: Careful, `sizeof a` is misleading there.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Good point, I was typing faster than I was thinking.

Comment: if I do 
    int a; std::cin>>a;
    int array[a];
is it dynamic? 
and if i pass an array by pointers will the changes be made on the array or on a copy of the array?

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha: No, that's an automatic array; it's dynamic if you use `new`, in which case you only have a pointer, not the array itself. If you pass a pointer, the changes will be made to the array, since that's what the pointer points to.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha `int array[a]` won't compile if `a` is not a constant.

Comment: @Johan i use that all the time. Speaking from experience I think it will.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha: Some compilers accept variable-length arrays as a non-standard extension. Don't use them if you want to write portable code.

Comment: @Mike Seymore i will keep that in mind. I think a vector here would have been more neat. But i am a newbie, any links to learning about them is welcome.

Comment: @SoumadeepSaha I did not even know it was accepted by some compilers.:)

Answer (score 1):

C++ Standard 8.3.2/4 clearly says that:

**There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references, and no pointers to references**

Actually a reference must always refer to something - there is no such thing as a null reference. This is why there can be no arrays of references, as there is no way to default instantiate references inside an array to a meaningful value.
-Source is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321578/c-why-cant-we-have-references-to-references-or-array-of-references).

And also By origin array is accessed via pointer arithmatic. So if we want to support array of reference we have to support pointer to reference, as per standard which is not possible.
These are reason array of reference is not possible. Which is what you were doing.

And as Mike Seymour mentioned :
`void repfunc(int a[], int size)` is perfectly ok for your case.