# Why it is impossible to create an array of references in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

C++ Standard 8.3.2/4 says:

> There shall be no references to
>   references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references.

But I can't understand why this restriction is added to c++. In my opinion the code bellow can easily be compiled and work? What is the real cause of this restriction?

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
int &c[] = {a, b};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are arrays of references illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because indexation into an array is actually defined in terms of an implicit conversion to a pointer, then pointer arithmetic.  So to support this, you'd have to also support pointers to references, and define what pointer arithmetic means on them.

Answer (score 5):

Because references aren't objects. References were primarily introduced to support call by reference and return by reference without inserting `&` at call-site. What you probably want is an array of pointers.

Answer (score 5):

A reference cannot be reassigned, and has no size.

If arrays of references were allowed they would therefore have to be treated in a special way then.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i read at:

**5.2.1 Subscripting [expr.sub]**

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an
>   expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the
>   expressions shall have the type
>   “pointer to T and the other shall have
>   enumeration or integral type. The
>   result is an lvalue of type “T.” The
>   type “T” shall be a completely-defined
>   object type.61) The expression E1[E2]
>   is identical (by definition) to
>   *((E1)+(E2)) [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for
>   details of arrays. —end note ]

-C++ Draft.

```
int a = 10, b = 20;
int &c[] = {a, b};
```

So imagine `&c[0]` would be *something* like `*&(c+0)`, IMHO references are like aliases. Hence going by the notion of arrays it would try to dereference the value held by the reference which one would not want.