# Is it possible to have an array with int values and int references?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Is it possible to have an array with int values and int references?

Is there any other way to have an array `arr` such that when you print `arr[1]` it always prints the value of `arr[0]` (without having to update `arr[1]` when `arr[0]` is modified) ?

Comment: An array has to contain elements of the same type. `int` and `int&` are different, so no

Comment: What are you intending to do?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please detail your actual problem.

Comment: You can't have an array of **any** references. You can have an array of reference wrappers, which are pointers in disguise.

Comment: boost::variant<int, int&> would do this.

Comment: Smells like XY. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Slightly tricky. You could define an array of integers and static cast the members. Problem is, an address on a 64 bit system is, well 64 bit and standard integer only 32 bit. Otherwise define your own class and overload the [] operator. Nevertheless even though this should accomplish what you want, I do not find it particularly useful

Answer (score 0):

[No](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5460562/3709765), but you may have such a desired array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CIntRef
{
public:
    CIntRef(const int & ref) : ref(ref) {}
    operator const int &() { return ref; }
    const int& operator=(const int &i) {
        const_cast<int&>(ref) = i;
        return ref;
    }
private:
    const int & ref;
};

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    CIntRef arr[] = { a, a, 0, 1 };
    cout << arr[1] << endl; // <-- prints: 2
    arr[0] = 3;
    cout << arr[1] << endl; // <-- prints: 3
    return 0;
}
```