# Passing by reference to a template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I'm having a function of finding max and I want to send static array via reference, Why isn't this possible?

```
template <class T>
T findMax(const T &arr, int size){...}

int main{
  int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
  findMax(arr, 5); // I cannot send it this way, why?
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use `int main()` (Notice `int` and `()`)

Comment: Was for explanation only, I agree about the int (I will edit it, thanks).

Answer (score 7):

Use correct syntax. Change signature to:

```
template <class T, size_t size>
T findMax(const T (&arr)[size]){...}
```

Or you can use `std::array` argument for `findMax()` function.

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/I4pzuK)

> Why isn't this possible?

`const T &arr`: Here `arr` is a reference of type `T` and not the reference to array of type `T` as you might think. So you need `[..]` after `arr`. But then it will decay to a pointer.
Here you can change the binding with `()` and use `const T (&arr)[SIZE]`.

For more, you can try to explore the difference between `const T &arr[N]` v/s `const T (&arr)[N]`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you did?, What standard is this syntax? And will it work on any kind of array?

Comment: I hope this is clearer after editing. I hope it helps you.

Comment: `T &arr[N]` is an array of references [which is illegal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460562/why-it-is-impossible-to-create-an-array-of-references-in-c), but `T (&arr)[N]` is a reference to `T` array which is perfectly valid.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Thanks for the link