# How to interprete - type *(& variable)

Tags: c++

Would someone please explain a little about the syntax below ?

```
void initList_v(Room *(& roomsList_p)[3])
{
  roomsList_p[3] = new Room[3];
}
```

What is the significance of *(&) in the signature of the function ? This is not a function pointer. Would anyone help me in understand this ?

Comment: `roomsList_p` is a reference to an array of 3 `Room *`'s .

Comment: The assignment statement probably writes out of bounds

Comment: See the [clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @M.M. Why do we need a reference here though we got a pointer ?

Comment: You didn't get a pointer. You got an array of 3 pointers. It is using "pass by reference" .

Comment: What about  void createRoom_v(Room* (&room) ? Can we re-write it as void createRoom_v(Room **room) if we pass the pointer base address to function createRoom_v() ?

Comment: You could but that would be a bad idea compared to using pass-by-reference which the language supports natively

Comment: I appreciate your help @M.M Thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

To interpret a type of a variable, unwrap it from the inside out:

> `Room *(& roomsList_p)[3]`

- `roomsList_p`: `roomsList_p` is a
- `&`: reference to
- `[3]`: an array of three
- `*`: pointers to
- `Room`: `Room` instances.

Why would someone make a reference to an array when an array decays to a pointer anyway, and the function could be declared like this:

`void initList_v(Room *roomsList_p[3])`

It is for type safety: precisely because the array decays to a pointer, the declared size of the array parameter is ignored. But when the parameter is declared as a reference, callers are forced to pass arrays of the declared size.

---

Side note: Since brackets `[]` bind stronger than pointer `*` and reference `&`, parentheses have to be used to disambiguate the reference:

`Room *& roomsList_p[3]`

would be illegal, because that would have to be interpreted as an array of references to something, but [arrays of references are not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460562/why-it-is-impossible-to-create-an-array-of-references-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you found this code, however, I wouldn't recommend using it unless you have to.
Let's break it down, if you would be writing: `Room name[3]`, it would mean an array to 3 Rooms. It has been extended to `Room* name[3]` to become an array to 3 pointers to Room. And following that, it has been given reference semantics `Room* &name[3]`. Unfortunately, this doesn't compile, as it gets interpret to an array of to 3 references to points of Room, hence the parenthesis, which make this:

```
 Room *(& name)[3]
```

My recommendation would be to use C++ structures instead of the C ones, by using the standard library `<array>`.

```
void initList_v(std::array<Room *, 3> &roomsList_p)
{
    roomsList_p[3] = new Room[3];
}
```

As it's bad practice to have raw pointers with ownership, this even could become updated:

```
void initList_v(std::array<std::unique_ptr<Room[]>, 3> &roomsList_p)
{
    roomsList_p[3] = std::make_unique<Room[]>(3);
}
```

And as returning by output arguments is also bad practice, it makes more sense to actually return.

```
auto initList_v()
{
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Room[]>, 3> roomsList_p;
    roomsList_p[3] = std::make_unique<Room[]>(3);
    return roomsList_p;
}
```

Some final advice: You code contains a bug, as you are indexing out-of-bounds.

Answer (score -2):

&roomsList_p is an array reference (address)  and (& roomsList_p)[3] refers to its 3rd element.

Room *(& roomsList_p)[3] mean "(& roomsList_p)[3]" is a pointer of Type Room

( as the name implies, the roomsList_p is an array/list of pointers to type Room )