# C++ creating a variable from a function type

Tags: c++, function, structure

I am trying to link my `student_info` structure with my `read_name` function but I am having issues getting it to work properly and it won't compile. The errors I am getting now are `error: ‘first_name’ was not declared in this scope` and `error: ‘last_name’ was not declared in this scope`. I declared them in the structure however.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Place your structure here for Step #1:

struct student_info 
{
  char first_name[15];
  char last_name[15];
  char crn[15];
  char course_designator[15];
  int section;
};


//Place any prototypes that use the structure here:

void read_name(student_info & first_name[], student_info & last_name[])
{
  cout << "enter first name" << endl;
  cin.getline(first_name, 15, '\n'); 
  cout << "enter last name" << endl;
  cin.getline(last_name, 15, '\n');
  first[0] = toupper(first_name[0]);
  last[0] = toupper(last_name[0]); 
  cout << "your name is " << first_name << " " <<  last_name << endl;
}

int main()    
{
  //For Step #2, create a variable of the struct here:

  student_info student;

  read_name(first_name, last_name);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors...?

Comment: error: declaration of ‘first_name’ as array of references
25:43: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘,’ token
25:58: error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token

Comment: `read_name` expects to receive 2 arguments, you're calling it with no arguments.

Comment: Specify the "few errors," please.

Comment: @user3226213 Please put them in the question, so we can see where each error begins.

Comment: @Tay2510 Someone already asked that.

Comment: It's an error because you can't have arrays of references.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-arrays-of-references-are-illegal

Answer (score 1):

Things you can do to fix your problem.

1. Change `read_name` to take a reference to a `student_info`.

   ```
   void read_name(student_info & student)
   ```
2. Change the implementation of `read_name` to read the data into the `first_name` and `last_name` members of `info`.

   ```
   void read_name(student_info & student)
   {
       cout << "enter first name" << endl;
       cin.getline(student.first_name, 15, '\n'); 
       cout << "enter last name" << endl;
       cin.getline(student.last_name, 15, '\n');
       first[0] = toupper(student.first_name[0]);
       last[0] = toupper(student.last_name[0]); 
       cout << "your name is " << student.first_name << " "
            <<  student.last_name << endl;
   }
   ```
3. From `main`, call `read_name` using `student` as argument.

   ```
   int main()    
   {
       //For Step #2, create a variable of the struct here:

       student_info student;

       read_name(student);

       return 0;
   }
   ```