# declaration of ‘args’ as array of references Error

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am newbie in c++ boost , I having  a program trying to compile it

﻿

```
#include "Program.h"
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/address.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>

namespace ConsoleApp
{

    void Main(std::wstring& args[])
    {
            .
            .
    }
}
```

the error appear is

```
Program.cpp:11:31: error: declaration of ‘args’ as array of references
  void Main(std::wstring& args[])
```

anyone here can help me , is this code error ?
thanks

Comment: Well, what are you trying to do?

Comment: g++ Program.cpp -o daytime -L /usr/lib/ -lboost_system -lboost_thread -lpthread

Comment: This is not the complete code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is pretty much saying everything. `std::wstring& args[]` is array (`[]`) of wstring (`std::wstring`) references (`&`). You cannot have array of references - see [Why are arrays of references illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-arrays-of-references-are-illegal).

Note: you're coding in C++, main function should be following:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Your code

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

And AFAIK main function cannot be in any namespace.

Also, there is one more problem with your code - even if we *could* create array of references, there is not stored information about length of the array. You couldn't use it except first element!

Anyway, you can do following (replaced `wstring` with `string` because I'm lazy):

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    void Main(std::vector<std::string> &args)
    {

    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.resize(argc);

    for(int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        args[i] = argv[i];
    }

    ConsoleApp::Main(args);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I thought about "it should be `int main()`" and briefly posted a comment about it — but actually, it is a function `Main()` in a namespace and not the `int main()` where program execution starts, so it is not subject to those rules.  (I rapidly removed my comment.)

Comment: someone send me the code to compile it without modifying anything , should I tell him this is error ? or it is possible in new version compilers/older version ? thanks

Comment: @MuadhProgrammer No version of C++ compiler should be able to compile this. Also the code suggest that Main() is entry point of your application - and it's not in any current nor past C/C++ compiler.

Comment: @MuadhProgramme I believe there is an information missing - maybe it's different language, or C++ compiler extension.