# std::initializer_list and reference types

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

Can a `std::initializer_list` contain reference types (both rvalue and lvalue)? Or does one have to use pointers or a reference wrapper (such as `std::ref`)?

EDIT:

Perhaps more clarification is due:

I have a member variable, `::std::vector<std::function<void()> >`, into which I would like to forward a lambda object. This would usually be accomplished with `emplace_back`, but I wanted to do it in the constructor's initialization list. Alas, as I read, this would make forwarding impossible.

Comment: You mean something like `std::initializer_list<int&> a = {...};`?

Comment: @RSahu Yeah, or &&, but I've had class reference types in mind mostly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can a `std::initializer_list` contain reference types (both rvalue and lvalue)?

`std::initializer_list<T>` doesn't hold references to its elements. It uses *copy-semantics* by holding its values as `const` objects:

> > `18.9` **Initializer List** `[support.initlist]`
> >
> > An object of type `initializer_list<E>` provides access to an array of objects of type `const E`.

An `initializer_list` of references will cause a compilation error because iternally pointers are used for iterators:

```c++
#include <initializer_list>
int main()
{
    int x;
    std::initializer_list<int&> l = {x};

    // In instantiation of 'class std::initializer_list<int&>':
    // error: forming pointer to reference type 'int&'

    // typedef const _E*  iterator;
}
```

An `initializer_list` also doesn't support move-semantics as `const` objects cannot be moved from. Holding your objects in a `std::reference_wrapper<T>` is the most viable solution if you wish to maintain reference-semantics.

Comment: I believe they do support a kind of move semantics, as you technically _can_ "move" a `const &&`.

Comment: @user1095108 No they don't. A move doesn't happen just from calling `std::move()`, it's simply a cast to an rvalue. A constructor taking a non-const rvalue reference `(X&&)` is where the movement actually happens, and "moving" a `const` object will actually create a copy in some cases, and in others a compilation error.

Comment: I know, but nothing prevents a move constructor from copying, instead of moving, either. I'm just nitpicking.

Answer (score 8):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/initializer_list/initializer_list/

> initializer_list objects are automatically constructed as if an array
>   of elements of type T was allocated

thus they can't be used with something like `std::initializer_list<int&>`. The reason is the same for which the following gives a compiler error

```
int& arr[20];
```

> error: declaration of ‘arr’ as array of references

and that is dictated by the C++ standard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164306/1938163

Comment: So, I need to use a wrapper or pointers?

Comment: I'd say yes, something that you can allocate an array of.

Answer (score 2):

##### You do not need list initialization here

As others mentioned, you cannot use `std::initializer_list` with references. You can use `std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<...>>`, but it will prevent your from passing rvalues as arguments to the constructor, because `std::reference_wrapper` can only bind to lvalues. In other words, the following will not compile:

```
YourContainerOfFunctions C{ [](){} };
```

This makes usage of `std::initializer_list` in your case neither efficient nor convenient.

##### Use variadic templates instead!

I believe that is what you wanted to achieve:

```
class Foo {
  std::vector<std::function<void()>> Functions;

public:
  template <class... FuncTs>
  Foo(FuncTs &&...Funcs) : Functions({std::forward<FuncTs>(Funcs)...}) {}
};

void foo(){};

int main() {
  auto boo = []() {};
  std::function<void()> moo = []() {};

  Foo F{
      foo, boo,      // passed by reference, then copied
      []() {},       // moved, then copied
      std::move(moo) // moved, then also moved
  };
}
```

This requires at most one copy per argument, necessary because `std::function` always make a copy of functor object which it is constructed from. An exception is construction of `std::function` from `std::function` of the same type