# How iteration over parameter pack going through initializer_list?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Sorry for being vague with my question, but I just don't understand what does this function does and how. Code from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nhk8pF_SlTk&ab_channel=C%E1%90%A9%E1%90%A9WeeklyWithJasonTurner):

```
template<typename ... T>
auto sum (T ... t)
{
    typename std::common_type<T...>::type result{}; //zero-initialization?
    (void)std::initializer_list<int>{(result += t, 0)...}; //why 0 is here
    return result;
}
```

I don't know why but this piece of code seems so odd, it don't look like C++ to me. Semantically, this function sums all the parameters in a result variable, obviously. But I completely do not understand why it was written that way. Using initializer_list here seem like a trick to trigger iteration over arguments in parameter pack but still...

Why initializer_list is explicitly was cast to void? To not take up extra memory?

And how iteration over parameter pack is going? Why not for example `(void)std::initializer_list<int>{(result += t)...};` (it does not compile by the way).

Comment: This trick was common before [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) were invented in C++17. Nowadays, you can just write `return (... + t);` Before that, pack expansion could only appear in certain contexts, e.g. in a brace-init list. So to perform calculations over a pack, you arranged a dummy brace-init list where each initializer had a side effect you wanted. The value of the initializer doesn't matter, only its side effect. `(result += t, 0)` uses a comma operator - it says "evaluate `result += t`, then produce integer `0` as the value".

Comment: cast to `void` was to avoid warning for some compilers for unused expression.

Comment: `std::initializer_list<int>{(result += t)...};` doesn't compile presumably because `(result += t)` is not of type `int` or convertible to `int`. In contrast, the type of `(result += t, 0)` is always the type of `0`, which is `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I figured out the answer.

I haven't ever come across comma operator, so the line `(result += t, 0)` made to me no sense until your comments about EXISTENCE of comma operator and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do). So basically we initializing our list with zeros. And since I made type of initializer_list for integers, I can't write `(void)std::initializer_list<int>{result += t...}`, since returning value of `result += t` is `int&` not `int`.

So why don't we write `(void)std::initializer_list<int&>{result += t...}`? It doesn't compile, and I suspect that because [array of references is forbidden in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109650/12332444). So here's the solution to my problem:

```
template <typename ... T>
auto sum1(T ... t)
{
    std::common_type_t<T...> tmp{};
    std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<std::common_type_t<T...>>>{tmp += t...};
    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: *"I can't write ... since returning value of result += t is `int&` not `int`"* no, you can write that, at least if the `result` is of type `int`. *"So here's the solution to my problem"* Solution to what problem? Doesn't the code in the question work?