# Get sparse subset of array as references

Tags: c++, arrays

Is it possible to get a sparse (non-contiguous) subset of references to array elements?

Suppose I have array `a = [1,4,5]` and indices `pos = [0,1]`. I would like to get `b = [1,5]` without copying elements from `a`. In other words, I would like to slice into `a` and create a view called `b`.

The following errors since "*expression is not assignable*":

```
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::array<double,3> a = {1, 4, 5};
  std::array<double, 2> b;
  int c = 0;
  int pos[2] = {0,2};
  for (auto i = a.begin(); i != a.end(); i++) {
    &b[c] = i;
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't have a container of references. The closest you'll get is a container of pointers without copying of `a`.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::ref`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have direct references in a container. However, if you have access to C++11 [you can use `std::reference_wrapper`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/02b38f7dcee7bcd5):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main() {
  std::array<double,3> a = {1, 4, 5};
  std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<double>> b;
  int pos[2] = {0,2};
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(pos) / sizeof(pos[0]); ++i) 
  {
      b.emplace_back(a[pos[i]]);
  }

  for(const auto& viewer: b)
  {
      std::cout << viewer << "\n";
  }
}
```

Otherwise, just use `double*`.

Comment: Do you think this will be more efficient than a copy of the elements if the sparsity rate is at only 50%?

Comment: @Oleg Since `emplace_back` does the construction in-place and doesn't copy over a `reference_wrapper` this will generally be really fast. However if your data type is just a `double` I have no doubt that copying over a couple of elements will be fast as well. Which one is faster than the other? Only a benchmark can help you with that.

Comment: I measured execution time of this method against copying the values into a new vector. The `a` array has 1e5 elements, the sparsity is 50%, and the operation is looped 100 times. The copy is more than twice faster. Premature optimization bytes my a** once again...

Answer (score 0):

C++ Standard 8.3.2/4:

> There shall be no references to references, no arrays of references,
>   and no pointers to references.

[Answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal)

However you can have a container array of a class with a referance member (initlized on constractor) and implement a =operator, if it's worth the effort

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this statements, which explain why I get the error.