# C++ filling array with dereferenced pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

According to what I have found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal) question an array of references is illegal. Im kinda new to C++ and was playing around with pointers and dereferencing and the following code seems to execute just fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct A
{
    int data1;
    int data2;

    A (void) : data1(0), data2(0) {}

    // many more datas
};

int main()
{
    cout << "test start" << endl;

    A *a = new A();
    A arr[100];

    for (int x=0; x<100; x++) arr[x] = *a;

    cout << "test done" << endl;
}
```

what happens here under the hood? is a copy of the `a` object being put in every location of the `array`? if so, when returning a object reference from a function like:

```
A &function (void) { return &A(); }
```

is it the same thins as this?:

```
A function (void) {return A();}
```

Comment: Compilation error happens, since `i` is not defined.

Comment: sorry i changed the `i` when witing the question, they are both supposed to be `a` fixing now

Comment: `arr[x] = *a;` calls your class's implicitly declared copy assignment operator which copy-assigns each member.

Comment: so do function calls like `void func(A &a) {}` called with the command `func(*a)` also recieve a copy of the object?

Comment: No. In the `A &a` the `&` says `a` is a reference to the argument used in the call.

Comment: Where is the array of references in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question, `arr[x] = *a;` causes the program to copy all the data stored in the object to the specified array element.

For your second question, `A &function (void) { return &A(); }` appears to attempt to return the address of a function, but the format is incorrect.  Look up "pointer to function" for more information.  You could however, do this:

```
A test;

A &function(void)
{
    return test;
}

A &ref = function();
```

This way, you have an actual object in your program that can be used in a reference and your function returns the address to that object.  Which appears to be what you are trying to do with that particular function.

Edit:  Removed incorrect part of answer.  `A function(void) { return A(); }` **does** create an object and return the created object.

Edit2:  changed `return &test;` to `return test;` in `A &function()`.

Comment: "appears to attempt to return the address of a function". No, he's trying to return a reference to a temporary instance of A. The `()` is simply a explicit call to the default constructor. That's a bad idea offcourse, and it won't compile, but his intentions can be deduced from his next line of code in the question: `A function(void) {return A();}` which is perfectly correct BTW.

Comment: I know what he's trying to do.  And thanks for the info about the original `A function(void)` function.

Comment: Then what's up with the broken code ? Your function returns the address of `test` in a function that should return a `A&` reference,  it won't compile.

Comment: You are correct.  My mistake.  I have corrected the problem.