# c++ initialize array with each element reference?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

I'm a c++ beginner, I want to initialize an array so that the element of the array is actually a reference to a variable.

```
string string_1;
string string_2;
string strings[2] = {&string_1, &string_2};
```

Is this allowed? So any operation done to the array will be applied to the variables `string_1` and `string_2` themselves?

Comment: Read up on "references" and "pointers" in C++. These are different things, and you can't have arrays of the former.

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simulate an array of references:

```
using s_ref = std::reference_wrapper<std::string>;
s_ref strings[] = { std::ref(string_1), std::ref(string_2) };
```

Or just use pointers (that's really what `reference_wrapper` does underneath).