# range-based for loop over references

Tags: c++11

This is question is out of curiosity, not necessity. One way I have found C++11's *range based for loop* useful is for iterating over discrete objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;

    // handy:
    for (const int& n : {a, b, c}) {
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
```

I would like to be able to use the same loop style to modify non-const references too, but I believe it is not allowed by the standard (see [Why are arrays of references illegal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal)):

```
    // would be handy but not allowed:
    // for (int& n : {a, b, c}) {
    //     n = 0;
    // }
```

I thought of two workarounds but these seem like they could incur some minor additional cost and they just don't look as clean:

```
    // meh:
    for (int* n : {&a, &b, &c}) {
        *n = 0;
    }

    // meh:
    using intRef = std::reference_wrapper<int>;
    for (int& n : {intRef (a), intRef (b), intRef (c)}) {
        n = 0;
    }
}
```

So the question is, is there a cleaner or better way? There may be no answer to this but I'm always impressed with the clever ideas people have on stackoverflow so I thought I would ask.

Comment: Is your code really just setting the values to 0?

Comment: You could instead just use `std::ref`. That's about as far as you can get.

Comment: @SombreroChicken yes that is an improvement, thanks!

Comment: @SombreroChicken if you put that in an answer I'll accept it, it is an improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Picking up @Sombrero Chicken's idea, here is an approach with less typing:

```
template <class ...Args> constexpr auto ref(Args&&... args)
{
   using First = std::tuple_element_t<0, std::tuple<Args...>>;
   using WrappedFirst = std::reference_wrapper<std::remove_reference_t<First>>;
   constexpr auto n = sizeof...(Args);

   return std::array<WrappedFirst, n>{std::ref(args)...};
}
```

which can be used via

```
for (int& n : ref(a, b, c))
    n = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of constructing a `reference_wrapper` yourself you could use `std::ref`, that's as far as you can get:

```
using std::ref;
for (int& n : {ref(a), ref(b), ref(c)}) {
    n = 0;
}
```