# How are array of objects of reference type stored in memory?

Tags: assembly, x86, compiler-construction, javali

In my understanding, 
when creating a new array of primitive `int` objects with the length 10 there is a memory region reserved for `10*4 = 40` bytes.

Now to my question, when creating an array of objects of reference type, for example objects from the class A (described below), what is stored in the array? Is it the object itself, with a pointer to the vtable and all the fields or does the array just consist of pointers to the objects elsewhere?

Here another question follows, can I store an object of the type A in an array of objects of type B, and/or vice versa?

```
class A {
   int a;
   int b;
   int foo(int x){
      return x*x;
   }
}
class B extends A {
   int c;
}
```

Comment: There are no arrays of references. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1164266/547981). In case you simply meant array of objects, then yes, storage for the whole object is allocated in the array. PS: oh wait, your code isn't c++. Please tag with appropriate language.

Comment: @Jester Actually its Javali (https://www.ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/infk/inst-cs/lst-dam/documents/Education/Classes/Spring2018/210_Compiler_Design/Homework/javali.pdf), a educational language used by our lecturer. So therefore I think the answer is that it is a question of implementation?

Comment: @heysamhey primarily, it is a matter of the language you compile and its semantics.  Since I'm unfamiliar with Javali,I'm not sure how this exactly works.

Comment: In Java the native memory consumption is considerably higher (because memory management is "automatic" and you don't have control over it), so array of 10 ints will take 40 bytes + additional meta data (some of them probably directly next to the array, some other probably inside the Java VM to support the GC, etc.). The simple 10*4 is true only in languages where the memory/type abstraction is guaranteed to be zero-cost, like C or C++. As your language is some kind of hybrid and the implementation is left on students often, it's hard to tell... (generally the "reference" is pointer)