# C++: array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have an action that gets 5 vectors by reference:

`void ReadFromFile(string nomFitxer, vector<int> &n, vector<int> &s, vector<int> &o, vector<int> &e, vector<int> &a){`

I created inside the action an array of vectors `vector<int> ve[] = {n, s, o, e, a};` thinking they would be the same, but of course they are not... because after reading I find that ve[0] size is 5 and n size is 0.

How can I make an array of vectors but from the vectors given?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please show your code instead of describing it, preferably as a [mcve].

Comment: `ve[0]` is not the same vector as `n`.

Comment: yes, I noticed they are not the same. That's why I wonder how can I make an array of exactly the vectors given

Comment: Store the address of these vectors instead?

Comment: mmm but then I should do a vector of address seems... or not?

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;

void foo(vector<int> & a, vector<int> & b) {
    vector<int> vectors[] = {a, b};
    std::cout << "vectors[0].size() = " << vectors[0].size() << std::endl;
    vectors[0][0] = 42;
    std::cout << "vectors[0][0] = " << vectors[0][0] << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<int> one = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    vector<int> two = {11, 12, 13, 14};
    std::cout << "one[0] = " << one[0] << std::endl;
    foo(one, two);
    std::cout << "one[0] = " << one[0] << std::endl;
}
```

This code creates an array of vectors which are ***copy*** constructed from the vectors which are referenced by the references passed as function arguments.

Therefore, modifications of the vectors do not escape the function scope ... and you have the drawback of a copy.

Since you're using `vector<int> &` (a non-const reference) I assume you want these vectors to be "output" parameters. An [array of references](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1164306/1116364) is not possible, but you can use [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) to circumvent this restriction:

```cpp
#include <functional>

void bar(vector<int> & a, vector<int> & b) {
    using vref = std::reference_wrapper<vector<int>>;
    vref vectors[] = {a, b};
    std::cout << "vectors[0].size() = " << vectors[0].get().size() << std::endl;
    vectors[0].get()[0] = 42;
    std::cout << "vectors[0][0] = " << vectors[0].get()[0] << std::endl;
}

// Now use bar instead of foo with the above main function!
```

Comment: Yes, they are output oarametrers. I get this error when I try it `error: elements of array ‘vref ve []’ have incomplete type`

Comment: add `#include <functional>`

Comment: how would I do a reserve tho?

Comment: `vectors[index].get().reserve(capacity)`

Answer (score 1):

I tried myself to figure it out

```
void foo(std::vector<int> &a, std::vector<int> &b)
{
    std::vector<int> ve[] = {a, b};

    std::cout << ve[0].size() << "/" << ve[1].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << a.size() << "/" << b.size() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> a = {0, 1, 2};
    std::vector<int> b = {};

    foo(a, b);
    return 0;
}
```

This code works, the output is :

```
3/0
3/0
```

So it may be a mistake with your vectors initializations.

Comment: @Lucas Gras That is because you didn't try to modify either vector after affectation. The vectors are copy-constructed into `ve`.