# how to declare array of functions( or lambda) by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, function, lambda, reference

it is possible to declare array of function pointer

```
typedef void (*action_pointers[])();
```

but how declare array of function by ref?
I have use multiple try around below example but not found any solution.

```
typedef void (&action_pointers[])();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164266/why-are-arrays-of-references-illegal

Comment: You can't create an array of references.  But, you can create an array of [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) instead.